# About packages (in particular AUCTeX or ESS)

Tags: discussion, scope, packages

Are all questions about Emacs packages suitable for this page? What about packages as, for example, [AUCTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) or [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/)?

On [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) we already see several questions related to AUCTeX. Are such questions acceptable here? I am not talking about how to install the package (that's maybe too simple a question, but it's definitely on topic). I am talking about using and configuring AUCTeX for sophisticated TeX editing.

Another example is ESS (Emacs Speaks Statistics) which is a recurrent topic on [Statistics.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and also [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Should the advanced usage of such vertical packages be discussed of this website? Should it be relegated to the appropriate communities?

Comment: Funny enough, my problems with AucTex were the reason why I started the area51 emacs.stackexhange proposal.

Comment: Absolutely, the whole point of this proposal was to consolidate emacs! :)

Answer (score 17):

I think they should be on topic here.

Configuration of such packages have typically more to do with Emacs/elisp than a [statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) site.  I've actually [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157242/) [AucTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185355/) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12243/) on [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com), and the only people who seemed to have a clue were the two people who happened to be active in [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) development. Note that two of these three questions still don't have a satisfactory answer.

The wider TeX community is mostly not expert in Emacs lisp or Emacs at the level necessary to answer a non-trivial [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) question.

Similar comments apply to [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) and [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), for example, I think.

Comment: I'd like to add that some AUCTeX-related answers on TeX SX are rather poor from an Emacs Lisp point of view.  The answerer certainly knew AUCTeX, but less about Emacs and Emacs Lisp.  Many answers on TeX SX could use one or another review from an experienced Emacs user, and the purpose of this site is to bring these together.